# Angular Mat-Badge Position moving in Chrome

Tags: angular, typescript

Using the latest version of Angular. I am trying to use the Angular materials mat-badge to display the number of touchdowns a player throws but only in chrome the badge position is shifting when I increment the number. When running in firefox the badge position is as desired.

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<p>Touchdowns<span matBadge="{{touchdowns}}" matBadgeOverlap="false"></span></p>
<button (click)="addTouchdown()">Score Touchdown<button>
```

Here is the TS code:

```js
this.touchdowns:number = 0;

addTouchdown(){
    this.touchdowns++;
}
```

There is no styling applied other than the standard styling coming from angular.

Comment: Use word `this.` when you want to get to class variable not when you setting it. try to change `this.touchdowns:number = 0` to `touchdowns = 0`

Answer (score 5):

It is a known issue. Check out the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16992).
As per the workaround that helped me fix it (as advised in one of the issue comments):

> You can also just add "display: inline-block;" to the inline element that contains the badge.

Answer (score 1):

Using `mat-icon` to show the badge instead of span fixed it for me:

```
    <p>Touchdowns
        <mat-icon class="badge-icon"
        [matBadge]="touchdowns" matBadgeOverlap="false">
        </mat-icon>
    </p>
    <button (click)="addTouchdown()">Score Touchdown<button>
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me figure out my problem. The element needs to NOT be inline. I made the span display: inline-block and that fixed it.

You may not want to use a mat-icon if the mat-icon is conditional. For example I am displaying an img OR a mat-icon if I don't have an img to display, and you can't put a badge on img since children of img don't get displayed unless the img doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

You put your badge on the wrong element. Try to use it like this

```html
<p>
    <span [matBadge]="touchdowns" matBadgeOverlap="false">
        Touchdowns
    </span>
</p>
<button (click)="touchdowns++"> Score Touchdown <button>
```

You should use the `matBadge` on the element you want to have the badge.

See the angular material  [badge excample](https://material.angular.io/components/badge/examples).